# NextJS Deploy Next-auth 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Tags: deployment, next-auth, next.js13

good evening! Everything alright?

After finishing a login project with a database and NextAuth.js using Google, Facebook, and GitHub providers, I encountered issues during deployment related to domain and authorization.

While all the URLs and permissions were set for localhost:3000, there were no problems. However, as soon as I switched to the new domain that Vercel generated for me, I couldn't use any of the authorizations or connect to my database anymore. Since I'm new to this, I'm pretty sure the error might be in the environment variables.

I changed all the callback URLs in the providers' array from http://localhost:3000 to the domain URL that Vercel indicates as the correct URL: https://project-login-nextauth.vercel.app/.

Comment: I had similar issues because of a trailing slash on `NEXTAUTH_URL`, but without any nextauth configuration code it can be hard to clearly identify the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.